# Removing style from the very first h4 in div

Tags: html, css

I know this probably is really simple, but I have tried just about everything I can think of and could find on the web.

I have some html that looks like this.

```
<div class="shared">
  <div class="task">
    <h4>Title</h4>
    <p>Content</p>
  </div><!--.task-->
  <div class="task">
    <h4>Title</h4>
    <p>Content</p>
  </div><!--.task-->
</div><!--.shared-->
```

and I am trying to remove a style from that very first h4.

I have tried

```
.shared h4:first-child{color:blue;}

.shared h4:first-of-type{color:blue;}

$('.shared h4:first').css("color", "blue");
```

and it's in a loop so I cannot add a class to just the first div. Trust me I would if I could. Any help would be wonderful!

Comment: You really should be not adding the class in the first place, on the server side. If it's in a loop, use a boolean flag to keep track of the first iteration.

Comment: @xbonez I would, but it is an extremely complicated loop that has so much going on with it and the html is changing constantly. Plus I'm using this in several different places.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you want to change the `h4` style of the first `.task`

Give this a shot:

```
.shared .task h4 {
    color: red;
}
.shared .task:first-child h4 {
    color: blue;
}
```

Comment: keep in mind this will only work on IE8 and above... not a huge concern anymore, but just pointing it out.

Comment: +1 @PlantTheIdea - All in all, this type of thing should really be handled with a class name.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! Not really looking at ie at all (perks of on only working internally) so this was just what I needed!

Comment: To this day, I still always catch myself looking for `first-child` of the element rather than the parent, so I know the feeling :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
.shared .task h4 { /* Style of the 1st H4 */ }
.shared .task + .task h4 { /* Styles of 2nd and more */ }
```

CSS2 supported

Answer (score 0):

How about giving this a try:

```
$('.task').first().find('h4').css({color:'blue'});
```

This will return the first div that has class `task`, find any children that are `h4` and apply the style you want.

Or better, create a class for the CSS:

```
.FirstTask {
    color:blue;
}
```

and apply it:

```
$('.task').first().find('h4').addClass('FirstTask');
```

A bit more separation of duties that way.

**EDIT**

Clarifying because apparently the use of `.first()` is unknown ...

This would only return the first instance of `.task`, then find the `h4` under that first instance **only**.

[Perhaps the documentation can explain better than I can.](http://api.jquery.com/first/)

And if that doesn't do it, [here is a jsFiddle to show it works.](http://jsfiddle.net/DCd2S/)

Comment: I can't because then it would be applied to every h4...it's in a loop and that task wraps around every h4

Comment: it would NOT apply to every h4, thats what `first` does ... it returns the first object in the jQuery object loop.

Comment: But every one or those is going to be the first one inside the div of task

Comment: you are not finding the first instance of `h4` ... you are finding the first instance of `task`, and then finding the `h4` that are children of that first task. i can create a bloody jsFiddle to show if you want.

Comment: @masedesign - appreciate the feedback, especially since you already provided an answer that works better assuming you only want to support IE8 and above.

Comment: Even so, it's still not selecting the first one. It's not even applying to any of them.

Comment: you are telling me that the color blue is not applying to any of them. you did open the same jsFiddle that I did right? because it kind of is ...

Comment: I didn't look at a jsFiddel, I was actually applying to the code that I am working on. I really only put the js above to show that I have tried many things that did not work. A css solution was found and that is much preferable. Thank you for the help though!